# Shortest path GENERATION with exactly k edges in a directed and weighted graph (edit: visit each node only once)

Tags: python, networkx, shortest-path, adjacency-matrix

This following code is from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shortest-path-exactly-k-edges-directed-weighted-graph/. All credit goes to PranchalK.

I am dealing with the problem of generating k-edge shortest path. The code below gives the shortest "distance" with pre-defined k.
However, I will need the "path"
For the code below the path seems to be:
0 --> 2 --> 3 .
Edit: Ajay's code solves this problem. However, each node needs to be visited only once. I haven't mentioned this in the original question. I have included an extra data set to test it.

```
# Python3 program to find shortest path 
# with exactly k edges 

# Define number of vertices in the graph 
# and inifinite value 

# A naive recursive function to count 
# walks from u to v with k edges 
def shortestPath(graph, u, v, k): 
    V = 4
    INF = 999999999999

    # Base cases 
    if k == 0 and u == v: 
        return 0
    if k == 1 and graph[u][v] != INF: 
        return graph[u][v] 
    if k <= 0: 
        return INF 

# Initialize result 
    res = INF 

# Go to all adjacents of u and recur 
    for i in range(V): 
        if graph[u][i] != INF and u != i and v != i: 
            rec_res = shortestPath(graph, i, v, k - 1) 
            if rec_res != INF: 
                res = min(res, graph[u][i] + rec_res) 
    return res 

# Driver Code 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    INF = 999999999999

    # Let us create the graph shown 
    # in above diagram 
    graph = [[0, 10, 3, 2], 
            [INF, 0, INF, 7], 
            [INF, INF, 0, 6], 
            [INF, INF, INF, 0]] 
    u = 0
    v = 3
    k = 2
    print("Weight of the shortest path is", 
            shortestPath(graph, u, v, k)) 

# This code is contributed by PranchalK
```

Expected outcome is:
[0,2,3]

0 is the starting node, 3 is the ending node. The number of edges is 2. The path is 0 --> 2 --> 3

Edit: Ajay's answer is very very close. However, each node needs to be visited only once. I am sorry that I haven't mentioned this originally. Here is a bigger data to test.

```
    graph = [[0, 10, 3, 2,4,1],
            [1, 0, 3, 7,4,1],
            [2, 8, 0, 6,0,1],
            [4, 1, 3, 0,1,2],
            [3, 1, 2, 2,4,1],
            [7, 1, 3, 0,3,3]] 

Weight of the shortest path is 14
Shortest path is  [0, 2, 0, 2, 3]
```

Comment: And what are u, v and k? Are they all nodes in the graph?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! u is the starting node, v is the ending node, k is the number of edges

Answer (score 1):

Store the node which yields min. sum of weight for every edge length < k.

```
def shortestPath(graph, u, v, k):
    V = 4
    INF = 999999999999

    # Base cases
    if k == 0 and u == v:
        return 0,[]
    if k == 1 and graph[u][v] != INF:
        return graph[u][v],[]
    if k <= 0:
        return INF,[]

# Initialize result
    res = INF

# Go to all adjacents of u and recur
    k_minus_one_path = []
    least_sum_node = None
    for i in range(V):
        if graph[u][i] != INF and u != i and v != i:
            rec_res, path = shortestPath(graph, i, v, k - 1)
            if rec_res != INF:
                if res > graph[u][i] + rec_res:
                    k_minus_one_path = path
                    least_sum_node = i
                    res = graph[u][i] + rec_res

    if least_sum_node is not None:
        k_minus_one_path.insert(0, least_sum_node)

    k_path = k_minus_one_path

    return res,k_path

# Driver Code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    INF = 999999999999

    # Let us create the graph shown
    # in above diagram
    graph = [[0, 10, 3, 2],
            [INF, 0, INF, 7],
            [INF, INF, 0, 6],
            [INF, INF, INF, 0]]
    u = 0
    v = 3
    k = 2
    weight, path = shortestPath(graph, u, v, k)
    if weight != INF:
        path.insert(0, u)  # source
        path.append(v)  # Destination
    print("Weight of the shortest path is", weight)
    print("Shortest path is ", path)
```

Comment: Hey Ajay! Thank you! This is an excellent answer. Very very close. I haven't mentioned it in the question but each node needs to be visited only once.

Comment: Hi Yusuf, a visited flag can be maintained for each node and this flag needs to be checked in first if condition of for loop.

Answer (score 1):

By checking the existing NetworkX algorithms in [Shortest Paths](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/algorithms.shortest_paths.html) it seems none of these allows to directly obtain all simple paths between two nodes and along with the corresponding weights.

So it will be necessary to do both things separately:

- Compute all paths between two given nodes, and keep only those of length `k`
- And then compute the weight of each of these indivudual paths and select the one of less weight

---

**General Solution**

```
def shortest_path_k_edges(graph, source, target, k):
    '''
    Computes the shortest simple path with
    exactly k edges of a weighted graph 
    between the specified source and target
    ----
    graph: np.array
       Adjacency matrix for the graph
    source: int
       Source node
    target: int
       Target node
    k: int
       Amount of edges of the path
    ----       
    Returns:
       Shortest k length path    
    '''
    import networkx as nx
    # Builds graph from the adjacency matrix
    g = nx.from_numpy_array(graph)
    # Generates all simple paths (no repeated nodes) 
    # in the graph from source to target
    all_paths = nx.all_simple_paths(g, source, target)
    # Keeps only paths with k edges
    paths = [i for i in all_paths if len(i) == k+1]
    # Compute the weights of each of the paths
    # using the adjacency matrix
    weights = [sum(graph[i[j], i[j+1]] 
                   for j in range(len(i)-1)) 
               for i in paths]
    # Return path of minimum weight, and
    # corresponding weight
    min_w = min(weights)
    return paths[weights.index(min_w)], min_w
```

---

**Output**

Lets check the results with the proposed parameters:

```
u = 0
v = 3
k = 2
INF = 999999999999
import numpy as np
graph = np.array(
       [[0, 10, 3, 2], 
        [INF, 0, INF, 7], 
        [INF, INF, 0, 6], 
        [INF, INF, INF, 0]])

path, weight = shortest_path_k_edges(graph, u, v, k)

print(path)
# [0, 2, 3]

print(weight)
# 9
```

Comment: Excellent answer. However it failed when I tested with the following graph: ```graph = [[0, 10, 3, 2,4,1],
            [1, 0, 3, 7,4,1],
            [2, 8, 0, 6,0,1],
            [4, 1, 3, 0,1,2],
            [3, 1, 2, 2,4,1],
            [7, 1, 3, 0,3,3]] ```

Comment: Let me check with this example

Comment: Which nodes did you try? Same? @YusufBaktir

Comment: And what was the error? Are you feeding it as an array? You can't feed lists to networkx

Comment: Got ya. The example is array and arrays (adjacency matrixs) are easier to work with. So, arrays will be my preference. The error is ```AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'``` The parameters are ```u = 0
v = 3
k = 2```

Comment: Yes the error is because you are feeding it a list. Is it working okay now? Don't forget to accept if so so I kinow it solved it for you :) @YusufBaktir

Comment: It solved! As you said, I was feeding a list instead of an array!

Comment: At this point the only concern is the timing. For a small dataset like this, it responds at about 265 ms.

Comment: Yes.. the main problem is that it seems that there is no dirrect way to obtain all paths an also weights